# Modifying Webform checkbox markup

Tags: theming, webforms

I've already managed to modify checkbox markup for a bit but there's still something that I can't access. Current markup is as follows and here you can see the duplicate text of which last one should be removed:

```
<div class="form-item form-item-submitted-payment-methods-1 form-type-checkbox checkbox">
<!-- This LABEL seems to be unreachable; cannot remove/modify it -->
<label class="control-label" for="edit-submitted-payment-methods-1">
    <!-- This DIV can be modified via [hook_theme]_checkbox(&$variables) -->
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="edit-submitted-payment-methods-1" name="submitted[payment_methods][1]" value="1" class="form-checkbox checkbox require-one-edit-submitted-payment-methods">
            <span class="checkbox-material"><span class="check"></span></span>
            In cash (to a member or representative)
        </label>
    </div>
    In cash (to a member or representative) <!-- Duplicate and should be removed: how to? -->
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution was to remove "fake" label and wrapper div which was moved upper to wrap "control-label". All done in THEME_NAME_checkbox(&$variables){}.

```
    <div class="form-item form-item-submitted-payment-methods-1 form-type-checkbox checkbox">
<label class="control-label" for="edit-submitted-payment-methods-1">
    <div class="checkbox"> <!-- Remove this and add it as suffix/prefix for the element -->
        <label> <!-- Remove this also -->
            <input type="checkbox" id="edit-submitted-payment-methods-1" name="submitted[payment_methods][1]" value="1" class="form-checkbox checkbox require-one-edit-submitted-payment-methods">
            <span class="checkbox-material"><span class="check"></span></span>
            In cash (to a member or representative)
        </label>
    </div>
    In cash (to a member or representative) <!-- Duplicate and should be removed: how to? -->
</label>
```